# Kibana Vertical Bar Graph where in the X-axis I have buckets for the sum of values?

Tags: elasticsearch, histogram, kibana, aggregation, vega

Suppose I have the following data:

```
{"name": "John", "spend": 50 }
{"name": "John", "spend": 150 }
{"name": "Mary", "spend": 30 }
{"name": "Mary", "spend": 70 }
{"name": "Will", "spend": 10 }
{"name": "Will", "spend": 20 }
{"name": "Matt", "spend": 0 }
```

And I want to build a Vertical Bar graph where in the X-axis I have buckets for the sum of spends per name, and in the Y-axis, the Unique Count of names in the bucket, like this:

[image: vertical bars]

I couldn't figure out how to achieve this using Kibana 7.5. Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

After a while, I solved this using Vega. Since I already have the data in the elastic search, I used aggregations to format the data the way I needed using the following request:

```
POST /teste/_search?size=0
{
    "aggs" : {
      "spend_per_name_0_to_50" : {
        "terms" : { "field" : "name" },
        "aggs" : { 
          "spend_sum" : { "sum" : { "field" : "spend" } },
          "ranges": {
            "bucket_selector": {
              "buckets_path": { "spendSum": "spend_sum.value" },
              "script": "params.spendSum < 50"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "spend_per_name_50_to_100" : {
        "terms" : { "field" : "name" },
        "aggs" : { 
          "spend_sum" : { "sum" : { "field" : "spend" } },
          "ranges": {
            "bucket_selector": {
              "buckets_path": { "spendSum": "spend_sum.value" },
              "script": "params.spendSum >= 50 &&  params.spendSum < 100"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "spend_per_name_100_to_150" : {
        "terms" : { "field" : "name" },
        "aggs" : { 
          "spend_sum" : { "sum" : { "field" : "spend" } },
          "ranges": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": { "spendSum": "spend_sum.value" },
            "script": "params.spendSum >= 100 &&  params.spendSum < 150"
          }
        }
      }
    },
      "spend_per_name_150_to_inf" : {
        "terms" : { "field" : "name" },
        "aggs" : { 
          "spend_sum" : { "sum" : { "field" : "spend" } },
          "ranges": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": { "spendSum": "spend_sum.value" },
            "script": "params.spendSum >= 150"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "spend_sum_per_name_0_to_50": {
        "sum_bucket": {
            "buckets_path": "spend_per_name_0_to_50>spend_sum.value" 
        }
    },
    "spend_sum_per_name_50_to_100": {
        "sum_bucket": {
            "buckets_path": "spend_per_name_50_to_100>spend_sum.value" 
        }
    },
    "spend_sum_per_name_100_to_150": {
        "sum_bucket": {
            "buckets_path": "spend_per_name_100_to_150>spend_sum.value" 
        }
    },
    "spend_sum_per_name_150_to_inf": {
        "sum_bucket": {
            "buckets_path": "spend_per_name_150_to_inf>spend_sum.value" 
        }
    }
  }
}
```

This gives me the following data:

```
{
  "took" : 6,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 7,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "spend_per_name_150_to_inf" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "John",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "spend_sum" : {
            "value" : 200.0
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "spend_per_name_0_to_50" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "Will",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "spend_sum" : {
            "value" : 30.0
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "Matt",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "spend_sum" : {
            "value" : 0.0
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "spend_per_name_50_to_100" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [ ]
    },
    "spend_per_name_100_to_150" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "Mary",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "spend_sum" : {
            "value" : 100.0
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "spend_sum_per_name_0_to_50" : {
      "value" : 30.0
    },
    "spend_sum_per_name_50_to_100" : {
      "value" : 0.0
    },
    "spend_sum_per_name_100_to_150" : {
      "value" : 100.0
    },
    "spend_sum_per_name_150_to_inf" : {
      "value" : 200.0
    }
  }
}
```

And, using this Vega req to send this request and format the data:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v3.json",
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "spends",
      "url": {
        "%context%": true,
        "index": "teste",
        "body": {
          "aggs" : {
            "spend_per_name_0_to_50" : {
              "terms" : { "field" : "name" },
              "aggs" : { 
                "spend_sum" : { "sum" : { "field" : "spend" } },
                "ranges": {
                  "bucket_selector": {
                    "buckets_path": { "spendSum": "spend_sum.value" },
                    "script": "params.spendSum < 50"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "spend_per_name_50_to_100" : {
              "terms" : { "field" : "name" },
              "aggs" : { 
                "spend_sum" : { "sum" : { "field" : "spend" } },
                "ranges": {
                  "bucket_selector": {
                    "buckets_path": { "spendSum": "spend_sum.value" },
                    "script": "params.spendSum >= 50 &&  params.spendSum < 100"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "spend_per_name_100_to_150" : {
              "terms" : { "field" : "name" },
              "aggs" : { 
                "spend_sum" : { "sum" : { "field" : "spend" } },
                "ranges": {
                "bucket_selector": {
                  "buckets_path": { "spendSum": "spend_sum.value" },
                  "script": "params.spendSum >= 100 &&  params.spendSum < 150"
                }
              }
            }
          },
            "spend_per_name_150_to_inf" : {
              "terms" : { "field" : "name" },
              "aggs" : { 
                "spend_sum" : { "sum" : { "field" : "spend" } },
                "ranges": {
                "bucket_selector": {
                  "buckets_path": { "spendSum": "spend_sum.value" },
                  "script": "params.spendSum >= 150"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "spend_sum_per_name_0_to_50": {
              "sum_bucket": {
                  "buckets_path": "spend_per_name_0_to_50>spend_sum.value" 
              }
          },
          "spend_sum_per_name_50_to_100": {
              "sum_bucket": {
                  "buckets_path": "spend_per_name_50_to_100>spend_sum.value" 
              }
          },
          "spend_sum_per_name_100_to_150": {
              "sum_bucket": {
                  "buckets_path": "spend_per_name_100_to_150>spend_sum.value" 
              }
          },
          "spend_sum_per_name_150_to_inf": {
              "sum_bucket": {
                  "buckets_path": "spend_per_name_150_to_inf>spend_sum.value" 
              }
          }
        },
          "size": 0
        }
      },
      "format": {"property": "aggregations"},
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "fold",
          "fields": [
            "spend_sum_per_name_0_to_50",
            "spend_sum_per_name_50_to_100",
            "spend_sum_per_name_100_to_150",
            "spend_sum_per_name_150_to_inf"
          ],
          "as": ["aggregations", "vals"]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "yscale",
      "type": "linear",
      "zero": true,
      "domain": {"data": "spends", "field": "vals.value"},
      "range": "height"
    },
    {
      "name": "xscale",
      "type": "band",
      "domain": {"data": "spends", "field": "aggregations"},
      "range": "width",
      "padding": 0.05
    }
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data": "spends"},
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "x": {"scale": "xscale", "field": "aggregations"},
          "width": {"scale": "xscale", "band": 1},
          "y": {"scale": "yscale", "field": "vals.value"},
          "y2": {"scale": "yscale", "value": 0}
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "axes": [
    {"scale": "yscale", "orient": "left"},
    {"scale": "xscale", "orient": "bottom"}
  ]
}
```

I now can display this graph:

[image]

I know that it have a few limitations, like how to change the ranges of the histogram, and a lot of hardcoded scripts, but since I couldn't find the right way to do it, I solved this way. If someone figure out a more elegant way to solve this problem, please post as a answer!

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a .conf file and feed it to logstash??

Comment: No, the stack is only Elastic Search + Kibana. I indexed this data in elasticsearch using the Bulk API and I'm trying to make Kibana display it the way I presented, but so far, no good. I think I'm getting closer to it using Vega.